Ubuntu no longer working with NVIDIA RTX4900
I have dual boot (Windows/Ubuntu) on my PC.  NVIDIA appears to work 100% as normal in Windows.
But in Ubuntu, two problems:

Dual monitors work if I plug them both into the motherboard.  But one monitor works when both are plugged into my RTX4900.
I can't access CUDA from PyTorch.  At terminal:
$ nvidia-smi

NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver.  Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
So far, I have reset the CMOS on my computer and separately reinstalled the most up-to-date NVIDIA drivers.
Does a full reinstall of UBUNTU solve this?

Which Ubuntu release are you using? Which Nvidia driver and how did you install it? Your new hardware should take the Nvidia 460 driver, now offered via the graphics-drivers PPA through the normal install mechanisms (ubuntu-drivers and Software&Updates/Additional drivers). A complete cleanout of existing Nvidia pakages will be needed to install the new one, a full Ubuntu reinstall is not necessary. Please add requested information into your original posting, not in comments.

I did a complete reinstall.  I assumed that Ubuntu chooses the correct nvidia drivers automatically.  If I have to clean them out I have no idea how to do this.  I cannot boot into safe mode.   The complete install worked briefly but stopped working.  Effectively I have o my   I used the most recent Ubuntu on the Ubuntu website .  When I say “can’t boot” I get the log in window on one monitor but the keyboard and mouse are inoperable — impossible to tell if this is a mouse and keyboard problem or if the system is hung.

Oddly it appears to be working now after I rebooted for the 3rd time.
